# Серверная и клиентская валидация

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация

Доброго времени суток! Вся валидация происходит на сервере, для фронт у меня есть от бэков только url по которым происходит проверка. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом я должна вытягивать regexp с сервера на клиентскую часть? Не совсем понимаю последовательность действий, впервые сталкиваюсь с серверной валидацией, которую нужно перетянуть на фронт.

Comment: Мне непонятен вопрос. Насколько понимаю, у вас есть какой-то серверный метод которому Вы передаете данные и он возвращает ок/не ок. Тогда я не понимаю что значит "вытягивать регексп с сервера на клиентскую часть". У Вас какая-то регулярка на сервере и Вы хотите дополнительно проверять такой же регуляркой на клиенте или что?

Comment: @MakarovAV надо каким-то образом серверную валидацию отразить на клиенте. то есть, в случае ошибки будет появляться поле с конкретной ошибкой. но как выловить с сервера есть ошибка или все нормально с проверкой ?(там же на серв будет и описание ошибки приходить). у меня есть только ссылки по которым можно обращаться к серверной валидации и все. раз регулярки есть на сервере, мне их получается не надо писать

Comment: я опять плохо понял. Как выловить с сервера есть ошибка или нет? - Очевидно сервер должен сказать в ответе, есть ошибка или нет. И если есть, то какая.

Comment: ну то есть спросите у человека который пишет сервер/ посмотрите в серверном коде/ посмотрите в запросах что приходит в случае ошибки. Или вопрос в том, как вообще архитектурно такое организовывать?

Comment: И если кто-то мимопроходящий знает: как в so движке обращаться к никнейму с пробелом?

Comment: @MakarovAV спасибо, значит буду узнавать что приходит, то есть по сути мне  много особо писать ничего не надо будет, как обычная валидация, только инфу с сервера забирать и отображать в поле, в случае ошибки?

Comment: Это вам виднее, придется или не придется) Скорее всего просто запрос принимать и показывать ошибку. Главное понимать разницу между клиентской и серверной валидацией. Клиентская - это красота и удобство, серверная - функциональность и защита от злоумышленников. Обычно валидация есть и там и там, но нужно понимать, что они между собой почти не связаны.

Comment: @default просто вводите `@` и первую букву имени и Вам отобразится список допустимых адресатов. http://i.imgur.com/Fa7Cv9a.png

Answer (score 3):

Обычно на фронте отсеивают запрещенные символы и другие явные ограничения (например, длину), а после заполнения каждого очередного поля – отправляют AJAX'ом значение поля на сервер, он уже сообщает ок или не ок и почему.

Answer (score 0):

есть готовые проверщики валидации, судя по тэгам - это валидация на джей кваери: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/  или http://www.formvalidator.net/

если же регекспы перетащить из серверной части в клиенсткую, то копировать и вставлять включая голову, так как небольше различия всетаки есть !